# setting language to website in magento 2.0.2

Tags: configuration, language, magento-2.0.2, ubuntu

I need an italian language site but now is only in english.
I tried to change my default language but my site is always in english language.

My change was this:
Stores -> Configuration -> In the "Store View:" label, I selected my StoreView.
Then I went in: General -> General and set up "Italiano (Italia)" unchecking the "Use Website" checkbox.

I downloaded the file from this site (zipped xml italian files) and copied into my server:
https://crowdin.com/project/magento-2/it#

I have read this link
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html
In my server there is not this folder: "/app/i18n/"
Am I obliged to make the language package ?

Comment: keep English as previous and create on more store view ...editing label won't  work ...assume mywebsite is your website and english and Italia is your store views ...